# after_update is called when the object is only created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two classes and a `belongs_to` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  before_update do |user|
    self.foo = Foo.create
    self.foo.save
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update do |foo|
    puts "after update is called"
  end
end
```

When a user is updated, i create a foo and save it. But when i do that the `after_update` callback in the `Foo` is being called, which as far as i know is only called when the record is updated not created. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo#after_update` is being called because you are calling `save` on foo after creating it. So you are creating `foo` and then updating it after.  Remove the call to `self.foo.save`

```
before_update do |user|
  self.foo = Foo.create  # this creates foo
  self.foo.save          # this updates foo
end
```